# Data structure/ Retrieving elements parent

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

im looking a way to find out any common elements for two parent elements.
For example, parents here are 1 and 2 (Ignore the below values)

[image]

And the common value for those parents are 91.
Parent - value that is on top and has NO parent.
Next example : 
[image]

Here we have 3 parents. and quite a lot of common elements for them. : 
91,
92,
93,
911,
912,
931,
932,
9311,
9312.
Main problem is to get the comon elements. Mabey any suggestions on how could i store them aswell?

Comment: That is not C++ specific, but a language-agnostic algorithm related question. Also, did you already try anything? Any idea how you could solve this problem? Any particular point where you are stuck?

Comment: Well, yes, you are right, thats not c++ specific. Well, i was going to write some sort of recursive function mabey?

Comment: Which is the data structure you'll implement to represent the diagrams? A graph? I suppose a directed graph?

Answer (score 1):

Run a BFS/DFS (doesn't really matter which one) from the first node and store a visited bit for every node (say in a vector/array of bool).

Now run the same algorithm again from the second node. Every time you reach a new node check if it has been visited by the first run as well. If it was then the node is one of the common parents so output to whatever you want.